# memory leak on transitions between views in swiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift5

I have a problem. I have 4 views, the forward transition is carried out through .fullScreenCover (), on 2,3 and 4 views, I should have a back button, by pressing the transition to 1 view should occur, the problem is when I start switching between the views, it starts grow memory and in the debugger shows a lot of views, how to solve this problem? Or are there other ways to implement this?
P.s view should be displayed in full screen.

FirstView

```
  import SwiftUI
   
  class SanityCheck0 {
     deinit {
       print("\(#file):\(#line) \(#function) Called.")
   } 
}
   
   struct FirstView: View {
     @State var isPresentable = false
     private let sany = SanityCheck0()
   
   var body: some View {
      // Text("Hello, world!").padding()
           Button("Next", action: {
               self.isPresentable.toggle()
   
           })
           .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresentable) {
               SecondView()
   
           }
   }
       
   }
```

SecondView

```
import SwiftUI

class SanityCheck1 {
    deinit {
        print("\(#file):\(#line) \(#function) Called.")
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @State var isPresentable = false
    @State var isPresentable1 = false
    
    private let senity = SanityCheck1()
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 50) {
            Button("Next", action: {
                self.isPresentable.toggle()

            })
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresentable) {
                ThirdView()

            }
            
            Button("Back", action: {
                self.isPresentable1.toggle()

            })
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresentable1) {
                FirstView()

            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.yellow)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        
    }
}

struct Test_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SecondView()
    }
}
```

ThirdView

```
import SwiftUI

class SanityCheckk {
    deinit {
        print("\(#file):\(#line) \(#function) Called.")
    }
}

struct ThirdView: View {
    @State var isPresentable = false
    @State var isPresentable1 = false 
    
    private let sanituCheck = SanityCheckk()
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 50) {
            Button("Next", action: {
                self.isPresentable.toggle()

            })
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresentable) {
                FourthView()

            }
            
            Button("Back", action: {
                self.isPresentable1.toggle()

            })
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresentable1) {
                FirstView()

            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.green)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}


struct TwoScen_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ThirdView()
    }
}
```

FourthView

```
import SwiftUI

struct FourthView: View {
    @State var isPresentable = false
    @State var isPresentable1 = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack(spacing: 50) {
            Button("Next", action: {
                self.isPresentable.toggle()

            })
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresentable) {
                SecondView()

            }
            
            Button("Back", action: {
                self.isPresentable1.toggle()

            })
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresentable1) {
                FirstView()

            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .background(Color.red)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}

struct FourthView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        FourthView()
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your Back buttons, despite the title, do not go back. When you say, for example, in SecondView,

```
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresentable1) {
            FirstView()
        }
```

...you are not going back to the old FirstView; you are making *another* FirstView, a whole new and different FirstView, so that now there are *two* FirstViews in addition to the SecondView. You keep doing that, just making more and more new views and never going back.

The way to go back from the SecondView to the FirstView is to turn the `isPresentable` back on FirstView back to `false`:

```
 struct FirstView: View {
     @State var isPresentable = false // <-- this
```

You can do that by handing a binding to it on into SecondView. Example:

```
struct FirstView: View {
    @State var isPresentable = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Next", action: {
            self.isPresentable.toggle()
        })
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $isPresentable) {
            SecondView(firstIsPresentable: $isPresentable)
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var firstIsPresentable : Bool
    var body: some View {
        Button("Back", action: {
            self.firstIsPresentable.toggle()
        })
    }
}
```

And so on.

Comment: I tried to do this and I managed to make the transition from 1 to 2 from 2 to 3, but when I press the back button I go from 3 to 2 from 2 to 1. And I need the ability to go from 3, 4 and 5 to 1 view ... Or I'm dumb, but I don't understand how to do it haha

Comment: I explained the cause of the phenomenon based on your original code and I showed you code that works correctly.